# Hibernate Criteriabuilder Query with part of a compound id

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, criteriaquery

I have a class that I am attempting to query by "userid"

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CollectionPK.class)
@Table(name="collection", schema="mageduelsusers")
public class Collection{

@Id
@Column(name = "userid")
private int userId;

@Id
@Column(name = "cardid")
private int cardId;
...
```

Id class of

```
public class CollectionPK implements Serializable{

private int userId;
private int cardId;

public CollectionPK() {
    
}
...
```

Query code is

```
public List<Collection> readCollection(int id) {
    List<Collection> collection = null;
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Collection> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Collection.class);
        Root<Collection> root = criteriaQuery.from(Collection.class);
        
        ParameterExpression userIdParameter = builder.parameter(Collection.class);
        
        criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(root.get("userid"), userIdParameter));
        
        Query<Collection> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        query.setParameter("userid", id);
        
        collection = query.getResultList();
        
        tx.commit();
    }
...
```

Error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [userid] on this ManagedType [com.panda.userinfo.Collection]
```

Ideal query would be
Select * from collection where userid = 'userid';

How do I modify to make this work?

Pretty sure error is in the criteria builder section as session.save(). session.get(), and session.delete() all work properly

Update:
Did a little bit of testing and the cause of the issue is definitely root.get("userid")    Is there any way to check what Attributes hibernate has for a class?

Update2:
Capitalizing the I in   root.get("userId") fixes that error. However both forms still cause an error at query.setParameter("userId", id)

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate parameter registered with that name [userId]
```

Update 3:
Figured it out or at least made it functional. Hibernate was renaming things in the background. Solved by printing everything to find the correct parameter name.

```
for(Parameter<?> p:query.getParameters()) {
    System.out.println(p.getName());
 }
 System.out.println(query.getParameters().size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct your query in this way:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Collection> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Collection.class);
Root<Collection> root = criteriaQuery.from(Collection.class);
        
ParameterExpression<Integer> userIdParameter = builder.parameter(Integer.class);
        
criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(root.get("userid"), userIdParameter));
        
List<Collection> collection = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
   .setParameter("userid", id)
   .getResultList();
```

See also [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-param) of the documentation.

Comment: Probably a nessissary update but not causing this error. Did a little testing and its definitely root.get("userid")

Comment: What error did you get? Do you have getter for the `userid` field?

Comment: Sandard getter/setter. Tried a few different capitalizations

public int getUserId() {
  return userId;
 }

 public void setUserId(int userId) {
  this.userId = userId;
 }